# Ionic2 takes upto 30 sec to load app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

Using ionic2 and angular2 we build almost 13-14 features/module.

Used 8-10 third party npm depenedencies and ionic plugins.

**Packge.json**

```
 {
      "name": "Yugma",
      "author": "NxtLife Team",
      "homepage": "http://www.nxtlifetechnologies.com/",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "watch": "ionic-app-scripts watch",
        "serve:before": "watch",
        "emulate:before": "build",
        "deploy:before": "build",
        "build:before": "build",
        "run:before": "build",
        "postinstall": "typings install"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "2.2.1",
        "@angular/compiler": "2.2.1",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.1",
        "@angular/core": "2.2.1",
        "@angular/forms": "2.2.1",
        "@angular/http": "2.2.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.1",
        "@angular/platform-server": "2.2.1",
        "@ionic-native/camera": "^3.4.4",
        "@ionic-native/core": "^3.1.0",
        "@ionic-native/file": "^3.4.4",
        "@ionic-native/file-chooser": "^3.4.4",
        "@ionic-native/transfer": "^3.4.4",
        "angular2-moment": "^1.0.0-beta.rc.1",
        "intl": "^1.2.5",
        "ionic-angular": "2.2.0",
        "ionic-gallery-modal": "^0.1.1",
        "ionic-native": "^2.2.3",
        "ionic2-calendar": "^0.2.4",
        "ionic2-rating": "0.0.10",
        "ionicons": "3.0.0",
        "nxtlife-ionic2-rating": "^1.0.3",
        "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
        "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
        "typings": "1.3.1",
        "underscore": "^1.8.3",
        "zone.js": "0.6.26"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "^1.1.4",
        "typescript": "2.0.6"
      },
      "cordovaPlugins": [
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
        "cordova-plugin-device",
        "cordova-plugin-console",
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen"
      ],
      "cordovaPlatforms": [],
      "description": "NxtLifeYugma2: An Ionic project"
    }
```

**Ionic info**

```
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic Framework Version: 2.2.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.7
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Linux 4.9
Node Version: v6.10.3
Xcode version: Not installed
```

Too much frustrated to solve this issue with ionic2.
Guys most welcome for any suggestion or advice.

Comment: Is this for only the first time or live reload as well?

Comment: Not only for first time, Its always takes random time to load app

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'loading the app'? Do you mean opening it on a mobile device, if yes, which one.

Comment: @tusharbalar did u try all these flags: `--prod --aot --minifyjs --minifycss --optimizejs` ?

Comment: @IonicBurger I mean opening it on a android and ios device. It takes too much time to open app.

Comment: did you tried any optimization technique like preloading or lazy loading

Comment: @Dhyey i tried with --prod. But not success

Comment: Hello @Jonnysai, What kind of technique available in ionic2. please explain in short if possible or share some docs where i can gain more technique how to improve app.

Comment: @tusharbalar You can find documentation for [LazyLoading here](http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-and-lazy-loading-pt-1/)  I do believe this technique is only compatible with Ionic 3.x projects though. Given that they added `IonicPageModule` to `ionic-angular` in the 3 release.

Comment: @Sam5487 is there any other suggestion to achieve lazy loading. because that link which u provide is only for ionic3.

Comment: @tusharbalar did u also try `--release` ? eg:  `ionic cordova build ios --device --prod --release`

Comment: I just follow https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/issue-with-app-boot-time/97818/13?u=dhyanandra link

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Dhyey, in addition to minifying your files using the flag `--prod` when building, you might also want to do [Ahead-of-Time compilation](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#why-do-aot-compilation) using the Ionic CLI flag [`--aot`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/build/) (should work with  both v2 `ionic build` and v3 `ionic cordova build` commands).

As you mentioned, lazy loading is indeed only available in v3 (and is still tagged as beta/experimental) but AOT and minification alone should decrease your app's size/startup time.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow below links:

I assure you after following below links/docs you will get definitely result (at least 90%)

[Issue with app boot time](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/issue-with-app-boot-time/97818?u=dhyanandra)

[Ionic2 takes almost 30 sec to load app](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/12305)

After updating your ionic and angular version. you need to follow [Lazy Loading](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vGokwMXPQItZmTHZQbTO4qwj_SQymFhRS_nJmiH0K3w/edit).

After doing above changes my app boot reduce to 13 sec from 20 sec.

Thank you.